# Adblockplus blocking all ajax calls on Django templates

Tags: ajax, django-templates

Adblockplus is blocking all `Ajax` calls written on `Django template`. If I unblock the adblockplus, calls are working. What do I do to prevent this ?

I am using `Django 1.6` and `python 2.7`.

Comment: Maybe your AJAX URL path is defined as ads or tracker script. Did your path contains 'ad' or 'track'?

Comment: Yes. The url is '/advertiser/add_to_cart/'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, all the urls present in my `urls.py` file have 'ad' in it. I changed them and all `ajax` calls are working if even adblockplus is active.
Thanks!